How do you access non-filesystem entries in Windows File Explorer programmatically?
Windows file explorer shows some entries that are not accessible from the file system (ie java file read/write)  For example, the 'EPIX' entry under 'This PC' (a smart watch connected by USB) behaves like a USB file system in file explorer.  But doesn't appear in the '/' root directory from java/python/etc programming languages.  How can a program access the files under 'EPIX' as file explorer shows?

Notice I said under '/', showing that I'm unix sort of person who expects EVERYTHING to show up in THE filesystem somewhere.  Is there some way I can these 'devices' or pseudo file objects, like open a USB device by some name?
Workaround solution, and what these 'special folders' are
A partial solution, for MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) devices is described in
SuperUser mount with mtpMount and dokany,
which is to use 'dokany', a Linux Fuse-like implementation and MTPmount to mount my MTP device Garmin watch as a disk drive letter.
It appears that the Windows OS doesn't support accessing these (USB) devices in the file system.  The things, like my USB connected 'EPIX' watch and other non-filesystem thinks shown in Windows Explorer are a sort of subterfuge called 'special folders', that show up in the Windows Explorer 'tree' of files, but are not known to the OS.  Most of these 'special folders', like 'Pictures', 'Videos', 'Documents' and   'Desktop' reflect 'environment variables' that specify where in the file system these 'well-known' entities are.  Right click on them and view 'Properties' to see where they are mapped.
There other 'special folders', like 'Network', 'RecycleBin', 'Libraries' and 'ControlPanel' which must be implemented by Window Explorer 'extensions'.  Things like my 'EPIX' and various Android devices are mapped to MTP clients.
The result is that none of these special folders appear in the file system as Unix user would expect.

These are virtual objects in the shell namespace. You can find them by calling IShellFolder::EnumObjects on the MyComputer folder.

@Raymond Chen, that's a good lead, so these things are not really part of the operating system, but are 'shell folders' an artifact of the 'windows shell' -- the UI that shows the desktop.  Is there an underlying  object in the OS that you 'open' and has a 'file system' read/write api?  Do you only access these things through the Windows Explorer?

IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf(IID_IStream) will produce a stream. Specify the access mode in the bind context''s bind options.
